# Meta-analysis of log transformed and untransformed Y!

Tags: mixed-model, meta-analysis, normality-assumption

First off, it's difficult to title the question without the knowledge of the field, Please bare with me as I, very much a novice, attempt to explain the issue:

I have summary statistics for over a million variables. Each collaborator has mostly the same set of variable (around 90% similarity) and we are measuring longitudinal decline of a given measure, let's call the measure Y. We employed mixed effects linear models to analyse the data. Initially, all the models shared identical covariates, and we used the same formula for all datasets, with one exception. We ensured that the fundamental assumptions of the models were met, particularly the normal distribution of residuals. However, a complication arose at this point. To achieve the required normality of residuals, some datasets needed a transformation. As a result, we now have two primary groups of datasets that were fitted using the following models:

1. Y ~ Covar1 + Covar2 + BaselineY + Var1*time + (1+time|ID)
2. ln(A-Y) ~ Covar1 + Covar2 + ln(A-BaselineY) + Var1*time + (1+time|ID)

Both have fit the models using REML=TRUE option in *R* with package *glmmTMB* *version 1.1.7.*

In the equations above:

- Y is the outcome,
- Covars are covariates,
- BaselineY is Y at time=0,
- A is the maximum change detectable for this measurement tool. i.e. range
- Var1 is the first of the >1million variables that will be tested,
- time denotes time since baseline.

A highly reliable colleague (professor of mathematics) suggested that by standardizing the effect size of Var1 from the data produced by each formula, I could still perform a meta-analysis. In my mind, this is like attempting to meta-analyse oranges and apples together!
I appreciate all opinions on whether others think this single meta-analysis of standardised effect sizes is valid for identifying the effects of Var1 across all studies! Last thing I want is for *reviewer 2* to point out a design flow!

If this is not a valid meta-analysis, are there any suggestions for alternative methods? Due to limited sample numbers I am reluctant to meta-analyse separately. Particularly mindful of the fact that I have many more variables than samples and at some point I would have to do an elastic net type regression. For this preliminary phase of the study a method that could utilise all the datasets in the same meta-analysis would be wonderful (if it exists).

Comment: What is the coefficient you have interest in? If you have raw data, you can fit a single model with all datasets, which will be a multilevel mixed-effects meta-analysis.

Comment: The coefficient is the effect for Var1. I do not have access to the raw data, and will only get the summary stats from each collaborator! Each collaborator will also be blind to other collaborators data!